# How can I see what ports my hard drives are connected to?

Tags: usb, thunderbolt, storage, firewire

2011 iMac running Mavericks

I have a number of hard drives on my machine, including a standard internal drive, an external SSD on Thunderbolt, a standard external drive on thunderbolt, a standard external drive on Firewire, and a standard external drive on USB.

What I'm not sure of without crawling around and tracking cables and other investigative work, is which volume on my computer goes with which drive, and therefore which connection technology.  It's just been too long since I set it all up.

I thought for sure this information would be in Disk Utility, but it seems it's not (or I can't find it).  Then I thought for sure it would be in System Profiler (System Information) but it's not (or I can't find it).

How can I find out which connection technology is being used by each volume on my machine?

**EDIT**:  I was able to deduce which drive had to be which from process of elimination, since I found that System Information will show me (under the Thunderbolt heading) which drives are Thunderbolt, and I know from the sizes which drives they must be.  Still I would really like to have a simple direct way to figure this out for the future, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find this information in the System Information Utility. Did you try looking under Storage then selecting each of the listed items? On my system running 10.10.5 each of my connected external drives was listed and clicking on each showed what type of connection it was on under the Protocol type. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes that was the second place I looked.  The data is probably there but not in any human-readable format.  I just see things like "BSD Name:  disk2s2", Volume UUID, Protocol (USB or SATA), but nothing that says Firewire, Thunderbolt, etc.  The only item that shows as USB is the one item that I already KNEW was USB (a portable drive I plug in as needed for backups).  I can't tell which are Thunderbolt (there are 2) and which is the Firewire.  Also my Time Machine drive (a 5TB) doesn't even appear at all even though it's mounted & in use, which I really don't understand.